# List to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am creating a CSV from a list of values. CSV File gets created but the csv is formed as a single column. Actually it should be multiple rows with multiple columns, instead it forms as a multiple rows with a single column. I am using the following code

```
from random import choice
import csv
fileObject = csv.writer(open('Insurance.csv','w'),dialect='excel',delimiter=' ')
for i in range(0,175):
    current_list = list(choice(master_list))
    fileObject.writerows(current_list)
    current_list = []
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your intent is to write 175 rows, you need to use:

```
fileObject.writerow(current_list)
```

instead of `writerows`. `writerows` is used when you have a list of rows (a list of lists), and in this case you have a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about this delimiter? If my memory serves, the delimiter in a CSV file should be a comma (hence the name, Comma-Separated Values), and not a space.